# PHP get string value from Assoc array and convert it to string for comparison

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to create a piece of code which will dynamically set the maximum values of a slider on my page by finding the max values returned from my database using a PDO statement.

The problem I am having is that I cannot convert the value returned in my assoc array to an integer value, what am I doing wrong?

Example of PDO statement

```
       $maxHGPM = $connection->prepare("SELECT MAX(high_gpm) FROM pumps WHERE pump_type = :pType AND pump_category = :cVal");
       $maxHGPM->bindParam(':pType', $pType, PDO::PARAM_STR);
       $maxHGPM->bindParam(':cVal', $cVal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
       $maxHGPM->execute();
       $res3 = $maxHGPM->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


       $maxFGPM = $connection->prepare("SELECT MAX(flow_gpm) FROM pumps WHERE pump_type = :pType AND pump_category = :cVal");
       $maxFGPM->bindParam(':pType', $pType, PDO::PARAM_STR);
       $maxFGPM->bindParam(':cVal', $cVal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
       $maxFGPM->execute();
       $res4 = $maxFGPM->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Test code and integer conversion

```
       // TEST CURRENT SET VALUES
       var_dump($res1);
       var_dump($res2);
       var_dump($res3);
       var_dump($res4);

       // INTEGER CONVERSION
       $psiA = (integer) array_keys($res1)[0];
       var_dump($psiA);

       // PERFORM LOGICAL COMPARISONS
       if(array_keys($res1)[0] >= array_keys($res2)[0]){
            $psiOut = $res1;
       } else {
            $psiOut = $res2;
       }

       if(array_keys($res3)[0] >= array_keys($res4)[0]){
            $gpmOut = $res3;
       } else {
            $gpmOut = $res4;
       }

       var_dump($psiOut);
       var_dump($gpmOut);
```

When the code runs the value dumped by $psiA is 0, am I missing a step for variable conversion ( I am fairly new to PHP )

Comment: what's the output for `var_dump($res1);` ?

Comment: http://gyazo.com/a9c9218605b1ec04b9b8c0741e4ac7c3 - here you can see all the dump outputs - $res1 specifically is 'MAX(high_psi)' => string '14406' (length=5)

Comment: That screenshot looks as if it is working as intended, however here you can see the logical comparison is inccorect http://gyazo.com/13c52c76c9ac75303256d28b207b7605 I think its currently comparing it on string length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$k = array_keys($res1)[0];
$psiA = (integer) $res[$k]
```

Considering the fact that your arrays contain only one item at a time, this should also work for you:

```
$psiA = (integer) array_shift(array_values($res1));
```

OR simply:

```
$psiA = reset($res1);
```